# Possessive apostrophe correct usage in this example

Tags: usage, possessives

> It is a women's jacket even though the tag size 50 is men's.

Is this correct with the possessive men's ?

I thought **mens** in this instance, but it isn't a word?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112420/is-mens-a-valid-word

Comment: Mens isn't a word, and the sentence is not grammatical either.

Comment: You must [cite quoted text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). If you wrote that sentence yourself, then please say so.